# Clearly recognize a certificate in Windows certificate store

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate

I'm developing a library which generates XML data and signates the generated XML. I've installed a pkcs12 certificate (generated with OpenSSL from pem file) into the windows certificate store.

I'm loading the certificate from C# code with

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 cert = null;

foreach (var item in store.Certificates)
{
    if (item.SubjectName.Name.Contains("CN=IDENTIFIER"))
    {
        cert = item;
        break;
    }
}
store.Close();
```

In my case the CN identifier is: my prename + surname. The cert comes from a third party. So I think I have no influence on the identifiers.

And here comes the question:

Is there any way to identify exactly this certificate from C#. In future it could be possible, that multiple certificates have the same X509 parameters (CN etc etc).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that CN contains the same identifier (eg. when the certificate is issued for business entity).

Certificates are usually distinguished by one of following combinations:
1) Issuer name (not CN, but RDN, complete name record with multiple fields) + certificate serial number (it's unique within one CA)
2) Issuer name + certificate hash

If you don't know the issuer name before searching for the certificate, you can present the list of found certificates to the user and once he select one of certificates, store certificate hash for future reference.

On smaller systems (end-user's computer) the number of certificates in MY store is usually small and the chance of hash collision is minimal. On large systems the chance is higher and that's why Issuer name is used as well.

Comment: Thank you, IssuerName + cert serial number is exactly what I was looking for. IETF says: The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to each certificate.  It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique certificate).  CAs MUST force the serialNumber to be a non-negative integer. But what do you mean with RDN ?

Comment: I think the RDN is the Issuername which is of type X500DistinguishedName

Comment: @csteinmueller RDN stands for RelativeDistinguishedName. This is the type -- structure with multiple fields. NOTE: Serial number is an integer, but the length of this integer is not defined and serial numbers of 20 bytes long are not uncommon.

Comment: Don't forget the thumbprint. It my be the easiest way to identify a certificate.

Comment: I would also add the alternative names to this. @GregS, good point about thumbprints, but like serial numbers, it depends on whether it's about recognizing a specific cert or recognizing an identity (the cert could be renewed for the same name). Fingerprints tend to be the way for identifying a specific cert (in fact, that's what tools like `netsh` use to configure a specific server cert, for example).

Comment: @GregS that's what I meant by hashes and hashes alone tend to collide sometimes.

Comment: The chances of collisions on the SHA-1 digest of an entire certificate should be quite similar to those of collisions on the digest of the tbsCertificate part. If that happened (on tbsCertificate), that would mean that a certificate could be altered and keep the same signature. That would be quite a big deal, and that's hopefully unlikely, certainly less likely that two certs with the same DNs.

Comment: @Bruno I like 100% guarantees ;)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Eugene's answer...

The [`Certificates` property of `X509Store`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.certificates.aspx) is an [`X509CertificateCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.aspx).

You'll probably be interested in its [`Find` method and the `X509FindType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype.aspx). It offers a number of ways to search for a certificate. Strictly speaking, both [the subject DN and the subject alternative names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6) should matter to identify the entity associated with a certificate. However, few tools do this from a presentation point of view (this could get quite cluttered in a table for example).

As GregS and Eugene pointed out, the [certificate thumbprint (also known as fingerprint/hash in other tools)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14345/2435) will identify a specific certificate uniquely, irrespectively of its issuer. It [can be used with `X509FindType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734695.aspx).

Thumbprints are used in multiple places in the Windows/.Net/SSL world. In particular, [it's the way to pick a given certificate to install on an HTTPS port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx).